# MongoDB $skip + $limit duplicates in find results

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm using **$skip** and **$limit** in my aggregation queries for AJAX pagination in my Django app. Here is an example of my code:

```
art_cursor = Articles.objects.aggregate({'match': {'ntype': {'$in': [1,6]}}},
    {'$group': {'_id': {'title': '$title'}}},
    {'$sort': {'_id.title': -1}},
    {'$limit': 51 * page}, {'$skip': 51 * (page-1)},
    allowDiskUse=True)
```

So I've got some sorted articles pool and want to get an unique portion of them for every page, when user scrolls down.

But some of articles are repeated on different pages, that means if I'll put above code in **range(1,6)** loop (for getting all the articles from 1 to 5 pages), then some articles in result array will be repeated.

Which workaround could be done for it, or maybe another way I can do such thing?

**UPD1**
btw, if I remove **$sort** operation - there are no duplicates in result array. I have no idea why

Comment: Can you show some data and the results that are duplicated? $in: [1,6] will return values of 1 or 6, not 1 through 6. It seems to me that you might have duplicates in your data but with slightly different titles.

Comment: @Tiramisu this [1,6] means nothing about this problem - I just finding articles that matches 1 or 6 type. The duplicates are about objects in my case.

Comment: Also posted on DBA: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143399/mongodb-avoid-sort-limit-optimization. As noted there, the `$group` stage is what determines uniqueness .. and it looks like the `$limit` and `$skip` stages are reversed. Some sample data to illustrate the issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem is about **$sort** + **$limit** MongoDB optimization. When we got $limit right after $sort, MongoDB optimizer sorting only objects we got in $limit result.

Source (MongoDB docs): https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#agg-sort-limit-coalescence

Comment: That's an incorrect interpretation of the `$sort + $limit` optimization in aggregation. This optimization allows the aggregation `$sort` stage to only keep track of the maximum number of results that can be used by the following `$limit` stage (i.e. to efficiently allocate memory for the top-n results that will be returned rather than sorting the whole result set in memory).